# Squaring the circle

Tags: geometry

> I know that it's impossible to construct a square that its area  equals the area of a circle , but is the impossibility  of construction implies the impossibility of existence ?,  Can someone denies the existence of square of area $\pi$?

Please explain your answer

Thank you for your help

Comment: Well, do you believe the real numbers are complete? If so, then definitely there is a square whose area is $\pi$.

Comment: @Clayton I could not understand your comment. Do you mean $\sqrt\pi$ is not computable?

Comment: What do you mean by *"existence"*? A square with both sides $\sqrt{\pi}$ has area $\pi$. Does length $\sqrt{\pi}$ *"exist"*? You can certainly create a square, and say that in *psmith* units, the edges of the square are of length $\sqrt{\pi}$, *exactly*, and that its area is therefore $\pi$ *square-psmiths*. (We still define weight units, like the kilogram, this exact way; except that the weight is some non-transcendental number, usually an integer.) I am trying to not be pedantic here; I am expressing genuine puzzlement about the definition of "exists" or "existence" in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue of squaring the circle deals with constructing a square with area $\pi$. However constructing in this context means using only compass and straightedge in a finite number of steps. No one denies that there exists a square with area $\pi$ (just take side lengths of $\sqrt{\pi}$), it's just can you construct it? Where, again, construct is referring to using only a compass and straightedge.

Comment: thanks very much, i have an extra question:     Can it be constructed with tools other than      "a compass and straightedge" ?

Comment: @prayer smith Yes : a straightedge of lenght $\pi$

Answer (score 2):

It just means that $\pi$ is in a different set of numbers (it is not *constructible*). Similarly, if we start with natural numbers and are only allowed to add and multiply them, then we can never create $\frac12$ or $\sqrt2$ or $\pi$. That doesn't mean that these numbers "don't exist"; they're just outside the set of numbers that can be described or created with the given tools (which in my example is the set of positive integers).